# Bluetooth - not connecting

Tags: bluetooth

I can't get any bluetooth device to connect.  Not a single one.  Devices that worked a week ago no longer will.  All my bluetooth devices are listed but when I click "Connect" it will say "Connecting...." and then will go to "Can't Connect"  This is bad, this makes Elementary unsuitable for me as I a number of bluetooth devices I use.

I must stress this stuff used to work, now they don't.  This is not a good upgrade experience.

Comment: Try update your kernel and ig dont work try blueman

Comment: I ran the update to 5.1 and that is when it all stopped working.  I even tried downloading the new iso and testing bluetooth with the Live USB.  Didn't work there either.

So, I downloaded Ubutu 19.10 and tested it on the Live USB.  Works fine.

I really need the help of an actual Elementary Dev.  But, I have very little hope of getting any assistance from them.

Comment: you are really update your "kernel" ? sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04